# IE renders inline-block div differently than FF/Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

First, I'm using IE9, FF 29.0.1 and Chrome 35.0.1916.153 m. I have done quite a bit of searching, tried spans instead of divs, float instead of inline-block, different DOCTYPEs, adding a z-order, making sure each div had a unique ID, etc., etc. The problem becomes clear when you hit F12 in IE to look under the covers, IE simply renders the HTML/CSS differently than FF or Chrome. Here's the page. I have reduced this to its lowest common denominator.

http://iamix.net/p/ie-problem.html

The problem (as you will see) is the button text appears below the buttons on FF/Chrome, as it should, but on top of the buttons in IE9. When you look at how IE has rendered the page, it takes the first button_block div and makes it some kind of quasi-parent of the other three. FF (using Firebug) shows that it renders the HTML/CSS as expected, with each of the four button_block divs siblings.

Here's the IE & FF rendering:

http://iamix.net/p/rendering.html (guess I need a rep to directly post images... ooo, guess I need a rep to post more than two links, so I've put both images here)

The overall goal here is to have a layout that adjusts well to different screen sizes, including smartphones. The original has some media queries in it to adjust for screen size but I have removed everything I could with the problem still being present. The reason for loading the images in CSS is because different image sizes are used based on the screen size (which you would see if the media queries were still present). The full-blown HTML/CSS works well in FF/Chrome on the PC and on Android phones (which is the main target). IE is the stickler (as usual). Even as I've been typing this up I've tried about eight other things because I really don't want it to be something silly that I've overlooked.

Here's the basic code I'm working from where the problem still exists (from the first link above):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .button_bar {
                padding-bottom: 0.5em;
                text-align:center;
            }
            .button_bar button {
                border: none;
                height: 250px;
                width: 270px;
            }
            #first_button {
                background: url(http://iamix.net/p/first-button.png) 0px/250px no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
            }
            #second_button {
                background: url(http://iamix.net/p/second-button.png) 0px/250px no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
            }
            #third_button {
                background: url(http://iamix.net/p/third-button.png) 0px/250px no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
            }
            #fourth_button {
                background: url(http://iamix.net/p/fourth-button.png) 0px/250px no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
            }
            .button_block {
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 0.5em 0 1em 0;
                vertical-align: top;
            }
            .button_text {
                background: #FFFF80;
                color: black;
                display: inline-block;
                font-weight: bolder;
                text-align: center;
                width: 240px;
                word-wrap: break-all;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div class="button_bar">
                <div class="button_block">
                    <div>
                        <button id="first_button" type="button" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="button_text">This is the First Button</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="button_block">
                    <div>
                        <button id="second_button" type="button" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="button_text">And this is the Second Button</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="button_block">
                    <div>
                        <button id="third_button" type="button" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="button_text">Which would make this the Third Button</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="button_block">
                    <div>
                        <button id="fourth_button" type="button" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="button_text">And this the Fourth and Final Button</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML, button is not a "self-closing" tag, therefore, IE is actually doing it correctly. Just appending the `/>` to a tag does not automatically close it, as it does in XML. You need to do this:

```
<button id="fourth_button" type="button"><span>Button Text</span></button>
```