# Element "inline-block" has different position when used in IE or Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I also look at this question [IE renders inline-block div differently than FF/Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210773/ie-renders-inline-block-div-differently-than-ff-chrome) but this cannot help me.

This is the CSS code for my element (in html it's an invisible square link):

```
#box-scenario {
position: absolute;
margin-top: 43%;
margin-left: 37%;
background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
width: 11%;
height: 21%;
display: inline-block; }
```

The invisible square link is about 200px higher than FF/Chrome positioning.

Comment: Can you please make a JSFiddle which accurately portrays your issue. Also, maybe the html of the "invisible square link"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Fiddle for you too look at in each browser. I added a parent `div` with stripes and also added a red outline around the invisible link, so that we would have some reference points.

> The invisible square link is about 200px higher than FF/Chrome positioning.

For me, across all the browsers, the link renders at 3.5 bars above the bottom. Where does it render for you?

```css
#parent {
  outline: thin solid black;
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to top, white, white 10px, yellow 10px, yellow 20px);
}
#box-scenario {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 43%;
  margin-left: 37%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  width: 11%;
  height: 21%;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: thin solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <a id="box-scenario"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I solved using the div parent but assigning to it "position: static".
So at least, i just move over the below element in the original location.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your entire markup and style sheets. I would suggest, if you haven't done it already, is to reset all padding and margin using:

```
* { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
}
```

It removes all default margin and padding for every object on the page, regardless of the browser. This provides a nice clean slate for design and ensures that all spacing is intentional, explict, and ubiquitous across browsers. There is no reason not to do this.

You can always use `-webkit-margin`(s) (i.e., before, after, start, end). Same goes for `-moz-margin`.